# Issue with collection size

Tags: magento-2.1.2

I am getting a wrong collection size here..

I have 24 records and I am getting 34 as the collection size when I use 
`$this->getCollection()->getSize()` function.

This is causing problem in my pagination as well.

I tried but I am not able to figure out the issue here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

This is my collection code :

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright © 2016 Rocket Bazaar. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details
 */
namespace Vendor\Mylisting\Block\Product;

/**
 * @author Custom Team
 *  Created at 23 Mar, 2016 03:45:20 PM
 * @method getCollection()
 */
class Live extends \Vendor\Mylisting\Block\Product
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setCollection($this->getLiveProductsCollection());
        }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager */
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager', 'mylisting.result.listlive.pager'
        );
        $limit = $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit', false);
        $sfrm = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sfrm');
        $pager->setData('pagersfrm', 'l');
        $pager->setTemplate('Vendor_Vendor::html/pager.phtml');
        if ($sfrm == 'nl' || !$limit) {
            $limit = 10;
            $pager->setPage(1);
        }
        $pager->setLimit($limit)
            ->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    public function getParamUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('mylisting/product/index/', ['tab' => '1,0']);
    }

    public function getAjaxEditUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('mylisting/product/ajaxlive/', ['tab' => '1,0']);
    }

    public function getCurrentUrl()
    {
        return $this->_urlinterface->getCurrentUrl(); // Give the current url of recently viewed page
    }

    public function getSubmitUrlLive()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('mylisting/product/livesubmit/');
    }

    public function getImage($_product, $image = 'category_page_grid')
    {
        $productImage = $this->imageHelper->init($_product, $image)
            ->constrainOnly(FALSE)
            ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
            ->keepFrame(FALSE)
            ->resize(50)
            ->getUrl();

        return $productImage;
    }

    public function getProduct($prodId)
    {
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($prodId);
        ;
        return $product;
    }

    public function getProductOffers($pId = false)
    {
        if ($pId) {
            $vendorId = $this->getVendor()->getVendorId();
            $collection = $this->_vendorProductFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('vendor_id', ['eq' => $vendorId])
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['eq' => 1])
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_deleted', ['eq' => 0])
                ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', ['eq' => $pId]);

            // $collection = $this->getCollection();        
            //$collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', ['eq' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('pid')]);        
            return $collection;
        }
    }

    function getAttributeText($field, $value)
    {
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $field);
        return $value = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
    }

    public function getApprovedProductEditUrl($item)
    {   
        if($item->getParentId()) {
            return $this->getUrl('rbvendor/product/approvededit/', ['id' => $item->getId(), 'tab' => '1,0','super' => true]);
        } else {
            return $this->getUrl('rbvendor/product/approvededit/', ['id' => $item->getId(), 'tab' => '1,0']);
        }
    }
    public function getLiveProductsCollection()
    {   
        $ostock = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ostock', 0);
        $searchQuery = $this->getRequest()->getParam('q');
        $vendorId = $this->getVendor()->getVendorId();
        // $criteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        //$collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
        // $collection->getSelect()->join(array('vpp' =>  'rb_vendor_product'), 
        //        "e.entity_id = vpp.marketplace_product_id and vpp.status = 1" 
        //            );
        // $collection->getSelect()->where("vpp.vendor_id = $vendorId");
        //$collection->addFieldToFilter('vp.vendor_id', $vendorId);            
        //$collection->getSelect()->group('vp.marketplace_product_id');

        $collection = $this->_vendorProductFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('vendor_id', ['eq' => $vendorId])
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['eq' => 1])
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_deleted', ['eq' => 0]);

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['prod' => 'catalog_product_entity'],
            "main_table.marketplace_product_id = prod.entity_id", ['sku']
        )->joinLeft(
            ['cpev' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'],
            'cpev.entity_id=prod.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id=' . $this->getAttributeIdofProductName() . '',
            ['vendorpname' => 'value']
        )/* ->joinLeft(
          ['cpevw' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'],
          'cpevw.entity_id=prod.entity_id AND cpevw.attribute_id=' . $this->getAttributeIdofProductUrl() . '', ['vendorpurl' => 'value']
          ) */;
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

//        $get_cust_modelSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $data = $this->customerSession->getGridSession();
        $searchFrom = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sfrm');

        if ($searchQuery && $searchFrom == 'l') {
            $str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -]/', '', $searchQuery);
            $collection->getSelect()->where("name like '%$str%' OR vendor_sku like '%$str%'");
}

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('session-clear-product-live') == "1") {

            if($data){

            $product_live = $data['grid_session']['product_live'];
            foreach ($product_live as $key => $val) {
                $product_live[$key] = '';
            }

            $gridsession = $this->customerSession->getGridSession();
            $gridsession['grid_session']['product_live'] = $product_live;
            $this->customerSession->setGridSession($gridsession);
//            $data = $this->customerSession->getGridSession();
            }
        }
        //echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($data);exit;
        if ($ostock) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('lteq' => 0));
        }
        $sortOrder = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sort_order',
                                                   'vendor_product_id');
        $sortDir = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir', "DESC");
        if ($searchFrom != 'l') {
            $sortOrder = 'vendor_product_id';
        }
        $collection->setOrder($sortOrder, $sortDir);
        $collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
        return $collection;
    }


}
```

Comment: where you have declared $this->getCollection()->getSize() using custom or core?

Comment: Its in the "RB_Vendor::html/pager.phtml"  file.

Comment: I just figured out the issue. My collection was not right , I was missing the condition of store in my joins. Its working fine now.